# Extracting values from old dictionary into new dictinary using iteration

Tags: python, dictionary

I am struggling to figure out an assignment.
The problem set up is:

> 1. I have a list containing ratios ( `unique_ratio = ['0.05', '0.98', '1.45']`
> 2. I have a dictionary containing k:v as ratio:count the number of times ratio has appeared in a previous variable ( `dict = {'0.05':'5', '0.32':'72', '0.98': '21'}`
> 3. I want to iterate over the dictionary and extract the k:v for the ratios which appear in the unique_ratio list. I want to store these k:v's in a new dictionary `(frequencies = {})`

I am running pytho 3.7
I have tried iterating over the dictionary using for loop but am never able to extract the k:v pair. 
I am unsure whether I should test for i in unique_ratios or i in dict

```
for i in dict.values():
    frequencies = { k:v for k,v in comp_dict_count.items() if 'i' in 
    unique_ratios }
print(frequencies)
```

Everything I have tried has led to syntax errors. The above code leads to empty frequencies dictionary.

Answer (score 4):

You need a single dictionary comprehension for this. Also for a better formormance you could check membership using sets, reducing the lookup complexity to `O(1)`:

```
unique_ratio = set(['0.05', '0.98', '1.45'])
d = {'0.05':'5', '0.32':'72', '0.98': '21'}

{k:v for k,v in d.items() if k in unique_ratio}
# {'0.05': '5', '0.98': '21'}
```